# trouble triggering relay with Bluetooth on an Arduini Mega

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, arduino-ide

I'm planning to make a Bluetooth controlled relay. but i keep having problems triggering the relay with my Bluetooth entries.The data i write on my phone is displayed in the serial monitor but i just cant get the relay to turn off or on.i am using a single channel relay module and the HC-06 Bluetooth module.
can someone please tell me what the problem is?? this is driving me crazy. my Bluetooth module is connected to TX and RX respectively and my relay is connected to pin 13 of my arduino mega.

```
                                   Thank You in advance!
```

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bt(1,0);
int RelayStateOn =0;

void setup() {
bt.begin(9600);

pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

char val=bt.read();

void loop() {

if(bt.available())  {
  bt.println(val);
  }

if(val==1)  {
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  }
else if(val==0) {
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sending the binary number 1?  Or are you sending the ascii character '1'?  Try testing for '1' and '0' instead of 1 and 0.  Note the single quotes on them to tell the compiler that those are ascii codes.

Comment: @Delta_G yes i have tried both. i have even tried using letters instead of 1's and 0's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have a call to read from the bt in the loop anywhere.  You have a call to bt.read() at global scope, so val gets a value that was read before anything was ready to read.  So it most likely gets a -1.

You also have a call to avaialable before you have a call to print which implies that you don't understand what available is for.  It tells if there is more available to read.  So that should be around the line in loop that you're going to add that reads from bt not the one that prints to it.

To start with, where you have the bt.println(val), change that to val = bt.read().

Comment: your right, i didn't know what the available function meant. However, after changing the code as you suggested, my relay still isn't working.

Comment: i changed my initial if statement. it now reads: if(bt.available())  {
                                                                                   val=bt.read();
                                                                                }

Comment: And you've tried that while using '0' and '1' instead of 0 and 1?

Comment: Why would you try 'a'?  If your sender is sending 0 or 1?  If you are sending 0 and 1 through the serial monitor then you need to be testing for '0' and '1' in your program.  If you're sending with some other program then post that.  Edit your question and add the new version of the code.

Comment: Another important question.  Why are you using a SoftwareSerial instance on the hardware serial pins?  If you want to use pins 0 and 1 then just use Serial, don't bother with SoftwareSerial.  That simple thing alone may be why things aren't working for you.  Can you confirm that you are receiving over that?  You have a Mega?  You should not ever need SoftwareSerial with a Mega, it has several Serial ports.  Move the bt to Serial1 and use Serial to talk to a serial monitor and then print what you receive to see if you're getting anything.

Comment: I stopped using software serial and then everything started to work.Thank you man!